# How to associate two models in Laravel 9?

Tags: laravel-9

I have two models, `Book` and `Author`. Book has a `belongsTo` relationship to Author. How can I add an author to a book?

```
$book = new Book;
$author = new Author;
```

Tried this:

```
$book->author($author);
```

And this:

```
$book->author = $author;
```

Both don't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$book->author()->associate($author);
```